# Using QTDesigner with PyQT and Python 2.6

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, qt-designer

I'm new to Python and am starting to teach myself GUI programming (hopefully) using PyQT4.7 and Python 2.6

I just downloaded the whole PyQT/QT4 package (including QTDesigner) from the PyQT website, however it seems QTDesigner, which looks amazing to use as a newbie (since you can see all the attributes/properties/defaults etc) of each widget and visually edit the properties is great, but PyQT seems not to set QTDesigner to integrate directly with with PyQT and PyQTs python code generation scripts:

i.e.: Hitting "View Code", tries to run the Designer->C++ script called (uic) instead of the pyuic.py script, etc.

Is there a way to get QTDesigner to integrate closely with PyQT for code generation on the fly like it does with C++?

If not, does that mean I have to code the entire QT GUI within my Python IDE and lookup all the documentation and boilerplate code for every widget? (seems very inefficient and inelegant compared to just having QTDesigner+Python integration).

What is the customary toolchain//production flow of using Designer with PyQT? (If no direct integration is possible -- do python+pyQT users just skip using QTDesigner all together and manually write all the QT GUI code in python?)

Any additional tips/suggestions for a PyQT newbie would be appreciated. Thanks!

ps I know a bunch of you are probably going to tell me to just suck it up and code all the QT UI by hand, but if I use Designer while learning as asked above, please provide a way to do that so  I can learn it more easily, thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I started to write my first PyQT application (PyQT is used only to handle GUI), and it seems, that good toolchain is: QtDesigner to generate .ui s and handle resources and some IDE, that can set QtDesigner to edit those. I use Eclipse, cause it is highly customisable.
You can compile your .qrc and .ui by demand by doing somewhat like this at application start, or at setup, or any other time:

```
os.system("pyrcc4.exe -o ui/images_rc.py ui/images/images.qrc")
uic.compileUiDir(appDir + '/ui', True)
```

and then using generated classes this way:

```
class MyMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, owner):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        # 'Ui_MyMainWindow' is the class, that was generated by uic, 
        # naming convention is: 'Ui_' plus the name of root widget in designer
        self.ui = Ui_MyMainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

or you can load .ui directly when container inits:

```
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.ui = None
    uic.loadUi('MyMainWindowUI.ui', self.ui)
    #now you have the instance of Ui_MyMainWindow in self.ui too, as above
```

note, that I have added UI suffix to .ui file's name, it was done to avoid name intersection , cause name of .py file, generated by uic, is not class name starting with 'Ui_', but just root widget's one.

And another one note: at the end of generated file uic places 'import %.qrc name%_rc' (by default is import images_rc) string, so you must aware this when using pyrcc4.

The whole approach is flexible enough, it takes all dummy ui coding work from you; but you still can do some fine tuning in MyMainWindow.ui attribute, where the instance of Ui_MyMainWindow lays; and it avoids unneeded inheritance. Personally, I make _connectSlots and _initIntefrace methods in MyMainWindow to do some work designer cannot.

Still I have to note that writing interface code by yourself is good approach, cause the code, generated by uic, is UGLY. I prefer to load .ui in place by loadUi() because of this :) And if you have a lot of custom PyQT controls, it is so booooring to bring them into QtDesigner..

Answer (score 2):

What I did was I made my own uic executable that's a wrapper for the pyuic.py script.

You'll need...

1. To get and install [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)
2. Replace PYTHON_PATH in the uic.py code below
3. Edit the qt.conf file in the site-packages\PyQt4 and set Binaries=Path to folder containing the uic exe once it's made.
4. Put uic.py and setup.py in the same folder
5. In the command prompt navigate to to the folder where setup.py and uic.py are then run the following command "python setup.py py2exe".

//----uic.py

```
#uic.py
import subprocess
import sys

args = ""

for arg in sys.argv: 
    if sys.argv[0] != arg:
        args += arg + " "


# Start pyuic.py script
command = 'python %PYTHON_PATH%\\PyQt4\\uic\\pyuic.py '+ args
out = ''


child = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
complete = False
while True:
    out = child.stderr.read(1)
    if out == '' and child.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != '':
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

//----- setup.py

```
#setup.py    
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(windows=[{"script":"uic.py"}], options={"py2exe" : {"includes" : ["sip", "PyQt4.QtCore"]}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run `pyuic` (or rather `pyuic4`) from hand, in your console. You can make your GUI using designer with Python, just as you would do it with C++.

By the way: I have written all GUI stuff for my app (10k of code) by hand. I don't really like GUI designers and working with generated code, when you need to tweak something.

Answer (score 0):

QtDesigner uses `uic.exe` to generate on the fly C++ code. `uic.exe` is a command-line tool, it gets file names as input parameters. For integration with python, you can write a python program that uses `pyuic.py`, match it inputs with `uic.exe`'s input (order, switchs etc.), convert it to an executable (using py2exe) and rename the executable to `uic.exe`. then replace it with uic.exe in Qt's bin directory (uic.exe dont exist in PyQt as I know). You should just be careful about input arguments of `uic.exe` and your hand-written macro (they should match together).

I think your program will need to know python's path (in order to use pyuic). if you are using windows, you could obtain the path from registry.