# Do you know of any effort to integrate PySide/PyQt development in Qt Creator?

Tags: python, ide, pyqt, qt-creator, pyside

I would love to program in python using *only* QtCreator. I have already used QtCreator to teach GUI programming to undergraduate students and they loved it. We have discussed several times the possibility of switching to python, but the lack of a good IDE to develop PySide/PyQt applications has refrained us to do so.

Comment: What's wrong with Eclipse/PyDev or eric4?
Their code completion seems ideal for teaching.

Comment: @something It seems you haven't worked with Qt Creator, yet... :)

Comment: I have, actually. Maybe I just don't get it.

Comment: You can't design the UI in any of those and integrate it directly in your code. Can you?

Comment: This might have some ideas for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489643/using-qtdesigner-with-pyqt-and-python-2-6
Does not integrate the Designer itself into your IDE though. But I don't know why that is so important. (I'm not arguing that Qt Creator isn't awesome)

Comment: It is really important if you are teaching programming to freshmen students with very little time to lose. I just don't want to spend my time in configuration subtleties

Comment: Without proper IDE like QtCreator, there are lots of uncomfortable manual task that you have done yourself : pyside-uic/pyuic4, pyside-rcc/pyrcc4 must be called manually for each changes in *.ui or *.qrc. And that's not a pleasant experience http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1zb0s1/a_complete_hands_on_gui_development_using_either/

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at https://github.com/PySide/QtCreator

Answer (score 1):

I think it all depends on how you treat Qt Creator while you are developing Qt programs. There are lots of cool stuff in Qt Creator but if we focus on 2 major parts: Code Editor & UI Designer, the situation is much easier to realize.

I think it's easier to just use the UI Designer part with PyQt and put Editor's task to something else. You can check this [Creating GUI Applications with PyQt and Qt Designer](http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Creating_GUI_Applications_with_PyQt_and_Qt_Designer).

Comment: Please read my comments in the main question (some are hidden and you need to click to make them visible). This is not what I'm asking for. Thanks anyways for taking your time to contribute.