# Qt Designer set "View Code" to always show Python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

When I click "View Code" in Qt Designer (PyQt4), it tries to show the C++ code.

So, the workaround is to run:

```
pyuic4.bat test.ui > test.py
```

to convert the file to `.py`.

Is there a way to execute the above workaround every time "View Code" is clicked or should I have to always perform it manually?

***The answer by @WithMetta in the duplicate solved my problem.***

Comment: PyQt4 is a library, not a program. What program are you talking about? Qt Designer? Qt Creator?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Qt Designer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using QTDesigner with PyQT and Python 2.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489643/using-qtdesigner-with-pyqt-and-python-2-6)

Comment: Note that while the *accepted* answer in the flagged duplicate doesn't appear to answer the original question (either for the duplicate or this question), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13461481/1994235) answer further down the page does.

Answer (score 3):

I personally load those ui files on the fly without generating python code:
something like this works for me:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui,uic
form_class, base_class = uic.loadUiType("unnamed.ui")

class MyWidget (QtGui.QWidget, form_class):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,selected=[],flag=0,*args):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent,*args)
        self.setupUi(self)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MyWidget(None)
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```